# Google API OAuth 2.0 CURL returning "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"

Tags: php, curl, oauth, google-api

I'm trying to implement Google's OAuth 2.0 authentication for a web server application.

I can obtain the code from Google ok, but when I post this back to try and get an access token, it always give me the error "Required parameter is missing: grant_type. Error 400" even though the grant_type is there.

Also if I specify the content-length to be anything other than 0, it throws other errors.

Here's the code that's doing this curl post:

```
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-length: 0'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 
    'code='. urlencode($code),
    'client_id=' . urlencode($clientID),
    'client_secret=' . urlencode($clientSecret),
    'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexperiments%2FnewGALogin.php',
    'grant_type=authorization_code'
));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $clientID,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexperiments%2FnewGALogin.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
));
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    'code=' . urlencode($code) . '&' .
    'client_id=' . urlencode($clientID) . '&' .
    'client_secret=' . urlencode($clientSecret) . '&' .
    'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexperiments%2FnewGALogin.php' . '&' .
    'grant_type=authorization_code'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use the PHP code in the original question plus answers provided here and kept getting complaints from the Google token server about a missing "grant_type", even though it was definitely being passed in.  It turns out the issue was the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER didn't like/need the 'Content-length: 0'.  Hopefully this complete working code will save someone else the same headache...

```
// This is what Google's OAUTH server sends to you
$code = $_GET['code'];

// These come from your client_secret.json file
$clientID = "your client id.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$clientSecret = "your client secret";
$redirectURI = "your redirect URI";
$token_uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';


$ch = curl_init($token_uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));

// Build the URLEncoded post data
$postFields = http_build_query(array( 
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectURI,
    'client_id' => $clientID,
    'code' => $code
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Save response, especially the "refresh_token"
$pathToAccessToken = "/your/path/to/access_token.json";
file_put_contents($pathToAccessToken, $response);
```

FYI, the response JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "access_token" : "xxxWhateverGibberish", 
  "token_type" : "Bearer", 
  "expires_in" : 3600, 
  "refresh_token" : "yyyMoreGibberish" 
}
```

After that I could successfully query the Calendar (the API scope my original OAuth request called for) using code like the following:

```
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $pathToAccessToken = "/your/path/to/access_token.json";
  $accessToken = file_get_contents($pathToAccessToken);
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($pathToAccessToken, $client->getAccessToken());
  }

  return $client;
}

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
      'maxResults' => 10,
      'orderBy' => 'startTime',
      'singleEvents' => TRUE,
      'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
          $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After researching into this problem, it seems like the grant_type is not accepted in the array format. (Yes, the query string method works but it's messy to build.)

Adding http_build_query() to the array works if you are keen on keeping the POST fields in an array.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array( 
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $clientID,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fexperiments%2FnewGALogin.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) carefully:

> ... as an array with the field name as key and field data as value

You do just something but not that. Try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => $clientID,
    ...
```

You don't need to `urlencode` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to believe it, but strangely enough, simply switching from CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS from an array to a '&' concatenated string (with the same data!) let my OAuth server finally recognize the grant_type.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue with the original question and some of the answers is the different values accepted in the `curl_setopt` call when using the key `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

When the input is an array the resulting `Content-Type` will be `multipart/form-data` which is not compliant with the OAuth 2.0 spec and the server will ignore it. When the input is a query-encoded string (e.g built using `http_build_query`) the `Content-Type:` will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is what the spec requires.

See the "Notes" section at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php